# Is it possible to have a single statusline in vim with multiple splits?

Tags: vim, statusline, vim-airline

Can I have a single statusline at the bottom of the window that changes to information about the currently focussed buffer?

Comment: No. It's one window -> one status line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Six years later, [this is now possible with neovim](https://gpanders.com/blog/whats-new-in-neovim-0-7/).

To activate put:

```
laststatus=3
```

in your `init.vim`

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot. I am unaware of any plugins that allow you to achieve this either. Basically the general property of the status line is to display information for a window so it is per additional window that you have opened.